# Digital switching of high voltage analog signal

Tags: switches, analog

I need to switch a 70 Vpp analog signal from a low voltage (1V8 or 3V3) digital output. The analog signal may or may not be isolated. What is the easiest and/or cheapest method?

Comment: Frequency of the analog signal?

Comment: 20 kHz to 1 MHz

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to use a telecom type [relay](http://www.components.omron.com/components/web/PDFLIB.nsf/0/51A3390695AC774885257201007DD58D/$file/G6L_0911.pdf).

[image]

All you need is a suitable relay driver.

They're fully characterized for the frequency range you're interested in (and well beyond).

[image]

Added in edit:

Since you need to switch quickly, something like [this](http://pewa.panasonic.com/assets/pcsd/catalog/aqv-dip-1500v-load-catalog.pdf) may work for you:

[image]

At 3ms it may be a bit marginal for 100Hz switching, depending on what exactly you're doing, but the 350usec (typical) models don't look too bad to me. You could always use a series/shunt arrangement if you need to increase the off attenuation.

Comment: Thanks. However, I need to do it around 100 times a second. Sorry for not including that info in the original.

Comment: I was looking at analog switches such as this one:
http://www.maximintegrated.com/products/switches/beyond-the-rails.cfm

Comment: What are the impedances involved? At 1MHz isolation may be an issue.

Comment: That device looks very nice! Impedances are >100 Ohms, typically approaching 1K at the frequencies of interest. The signals I am trying to switch on and off are not high precision, and are typically sine waves.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say exactly what "switching" means, so I'll assume you either want to apply this 70 V power to something else or not.

In that case, as simple NPN transistor as a low side switch would do it.  Since the base only needs 700 mV or so, it can be easily switched from 1.8 or 3.3 V.  Put a suitable resistor between the digital output and the base to deliver enough current to keep the transistor saturated when on.

To be safe, you should also put a reverse diode between the collector and the 70 V supply.  If the load has any inductive component, this will keep it from making a high voltage and frying the transistor when it tries to switch off.

Comment: The load is capacitative